# How do I call an instance in the main driver from an abstract class?

Tags: java, abstraction, delegation, karel

So pretty much I need my delegating class (ref) to be able to read instances of a class created in the main driver. I tried to create the class references in ref, but that only created more objects in the world and didn't make the original ones move.

Main driver code:

```
public static void main(String args[])  
{   
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot = new Sprint100Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot = new Sprint200Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot = new Sprint400Bot(1,1,North,0);

    AbstractReferee ref = new TrackReferee(1,1,North,0);
    ref.meet();
}
```

TrackReferee code:

```
public class TrackReferee extends AbstractReferee
{
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot = new Sprint100Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot = new Sprint200Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot = new Sprint400Bot(1,1,North,0);

    public TrackReferee(int st, int ave, Direction dir, int Beepers)
    {
        super(st, ave, dir, Beepers);
    }

    public void meet()
    {
        Sprint100Bot.run();
        Sprint200Bot.run();
        Sprint400Bot.run();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, I should have clarified, but we're not allowed to change the code in the main driver because it was already given to us, so I have to somehow make it work through only the TrackReferee class.

Comment: You should pass them in as parameters to the TrackReferee constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create references of AbstractTrackRobot in your TrackReferee class. When you create an object of TrackReferee. You will pass the AbstractTrackRobot class objects created in main. This way the object of TrackReferee class will have references to those objects of AbstractTrackRobot class that were created in main. Hope your problem is clear.

```
   public static void main(String args[])  
    {   
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot = new Sprint100Bot(1,1,North,0);
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot = new Sprint200Bot(1,1,North,0);
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot = new Sprint400Bot(1,1,North,0);

        AbstractReferee ref = new TrackReferee(1,1,North,0, Sprint100Bot ,Sprint200Bot , Sprint400Bot);
        ref.meet();
    }


    public class TrackReferee extends AbstractReferee
    {
        public AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot;
        public AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot;
        public AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot;

        public TrackReferee(int st, int ave, Direction dir, int Beepers, AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot, AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot ,  AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot)
        {
            super(st, ave, dir, Beepers);
    this.Sprint100Bot = Sprint100Bot;
    this.Sprint200Bot = Sprint200Bot;
    this.Sprint400Bot = Sprint400Bot;

        }

        public void meet()
        {
            Sprint100Bot.run();
            Sprint200Bot.run();
            Sprint400Bot.run();
        }
    }
```

***This can be an alternate solution as per your requirement i.e., without change in constructor***

```
public static void main(String args[])  
{   
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot = new Sprint100Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot = new Sprint200Bot(1,1,North,0);
    AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot = new Sprint400Bot(1,1,North,0);

    AbstractReferee ref = new TrackReferee(1,1,North,0);
    ref.Sprint100Bot = Sprint100Bot;
    ref.Sprint200Bot = Sprint200Bot;
    ref.Sprint400Bot = Sprint400Bot;
    ref.meet();
}



   public class TrackReferee extends AbstractReferee
        {
            AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot;
            AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot;
            AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot;

            public TrackReferee(int st, int ave, Direction dir, int Beepers)
            {
                super(st, ave, dir, Beepers);


            }

            public void meet()
            {
                Sprint100Bot.run();
                Sprint200Bot.run();
                Sprint400Bot.run();
            }    
        }
```

Comment: Yep, but I don't think we can change constructors :/

Comment: Can you add a method to the TrackReferee class??. In case you can there is another way of solving taht will sort out the issue.

Comment: Please go through the alternate solution. This should help you. No need to add more methods either :P

Answer (score -1):

in your main class,
public static void main(String args[])

```
{
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot = new Sprint100Bot(1,1,North,0);
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot = new Sprint200Bot(1,1,North,0);
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot = new Sprint400Bot(1,1,North,0);

        AbstractReferee ref = new TrackReferee(Sprint100Bot,Sprint200Bot,Sprint400Bot );

  ref.meet();
}
```

In your ref,

```
public class TrackReferee extends AbstractReferee
{

 AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot;
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot;
        AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot;

 public TrackReferee(AbstractTrackRobot Sprint100Bot, AbstractTrackRobot Sprint200Bot,  AbstractTrackRobot Sprint400Bot)
    {
       this.Sprint100Bot = Sprint100Bot;
       this.Sprint200Bot = Sprint200Bot;
       this.Sprint400Bot = Sprint400Bot;
    }
public void meet()
    {
        Sprint100Bot.run();
        Sprint200Bot.run();
        Sprint400Bot.run();
    }
}
```